# Selecting records based on association count (join?)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

Three models:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :visits
end

class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :visit
end
```

Now I want to return all of the customers visits in which they have messages. So in pseudo code something like this:

```
@customer = Customer.find(:id)
@customer.visits.where(visit has messages)
```

How do I do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do an [inner join:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join) (recommended):

```
# returns a customer's visits that have at least one message
@customer.visits.joins(:messages)
```

Make sure to deal with duplicates

```
@customer.visits.joins(:messages).(“distinct(categories.id, categories.name)”)
```

With possible performance issues, another option is to use [SQL EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) clause:

```
@customer.visits.where("EXISTS (SELECT messages.id FROM messages WHERE messages.visit_id == visits.id)")
```

Or [SQL IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp):

```
@customer.visits.where("visits.id IN (SELECT messages.visit_id FROM messages)")
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations